# How to use template context variable's value inside Django template tags?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-2.0

In Django, I have seen the `trans` tag, it is useful to place translation strings in templates.

```
{% trans 'Rishikesh' %}
```

But I want to use dynamic value in place of `'Rishikesh'` that is being passed by my view function.

Let you assume my view function named `index` is as follows.

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, "index.html", {"username": "Rishikesh"})
```

My question is, I want to use the value of `username` as value of `trans` tag in my template something like following.

```
{% trans "{{username}}" %}
```

I think, it should work but it doesn't work?

Please help me if you know any way to do the same.

Comment: What's with the random bolding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use variables without quotes and without braces like this:

```
{% trans username %}
```

Comment: Thanks @Farrukh. It is working.

Answer (score 2):

You should be doing translation in your view

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

def index(request):
    return render(request, "index.html", {"username": _("Rishikesh")})
```

And in your template just rendering variable:

```
{{ username }}
```

Template translations are for static only, don't put too much logic in templates, it would be hard to follow in some time.

Comment: I want to use the variable value as the value of trans tag. Now I got the solution from answer of @Farrukh. We can use  {% trans username %} and it works.